# Tensorflow .NET Аппроксимация логической функции

Tags: c#, .net, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras

Данный пример генерирует и обучает небольшую нейронную сеть с помощью Tensorflow Keras API:

```
NDArray trainSet = np.array(trainSetArr);
NDArray labels = np.array(lablesArr);

NDArray testSet = np.array(testSetArr);
NDArray testLabels = np.array(testLablesArr);

Tensor inputs = keras.Input(new Shape(4));
LayersApi layers = new LayersApi();
Tensor outputs = layers.Dense(12, keras.activations.Relu).Apply(inputs);
outputs = layers.Dense(17, keras.activations.Relu).Apply(outputs);
outputs = layers.Dense(1, keras.activations.Relu).Apply(outputs);

Functional model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs);
model.compile(optimizer: keras.optimizers.SGD(0.1f), loss: keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics: new string[] { "accuracy" });
model.fit(trainSet, labels, epochs: 200);

Tensor tensor = model.Apply(testSet);
Console.WriteLine(tensor);
```

Ставилась задача аппроксимации логической функции.

Таблица истинности:

```
  a  b  c  d  F
  -------------
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  1  0
  0  0  1  0  0
  0  0  1  1  0
  0  1  0  0  1
  0  1  0  1  1
  0  1  1  0  0
  0  1  1  1  0
  1  0  0  0  0
  1  0  0  1  1
  1  0  1  0  0
  1  0  1  1  1
  1  1  0  0  1
  1  1  0  1  1
  1  1  1  0  0
  1  1  1  1  1
```

Первые 12 значений использовались для обучения и 4 последних для теста.
Результат получился такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть сеть обучилась успешно. Последние 4 правильных значения это 1 1 0 1, что и было предсказано сетью.

У меня есть несколько вопросов по работе с данной платформой в .NET.

1. Каким образом я могу использовать, например, LeakyReLU в качестве функции активации? `keras.activations` предоставляет очень скудный набор функций активаций.
2. Нет возможности для начальной инициализации весовых коэффициентов. Бывает сеть просто не начинает обучаться и ошибка не уменьшается.
3. `keras.optimizers.SGD` не позволяет задать много гиперпараметров (например momentum). Как это можно настроить?
4. Метод `model.fit` имеет параметр `batch_size`, который, как я понимаю, нужен при обучении в пакетном режиме и определяет количество элементов в обучающей выборке?

Answer (score 1):

Wrapper это не всегда лучший вариант.Так как оригинальная библиотека может обновляться и расширятся намного быстрее чем враппер.
Поэтому могу посоветовать вам строить и обучать в python и там же конвертировать в onnx формат, а потом легко импортировать в .net.

Так как это враппер над питоновским Keras, не все методы и объекты повторяет оригинальную библиотеку.
Почитав на github классы этой библиотеке

1)Написать свой метод расширения для активации.

3)[Метод SGD](https://github.com/SciSharp/Keras.NET/blob/master/Keras/Optimizers.cs) все таки имеет такой параметр

```
 public SGD(float lr = 0.01f, float momentum = 0.0f, float decay = 0.0f, bool nesterov = false)
```

4)Да,вы правильно понимаете.

Надеюсь чем то помог или навел на какие-то идеи